# Availability of Google Map API

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I need to implement Branch Locator functionality where user can search for bank's branch using Google Map.

I understand that to make this work, Google Map library needs to be available on the phone else my code won't work. 
Is this understanding correct?

If this is correct than is there some URL from where the user can download Google Map Library?

Comment: Yes. You just have to create Android Project -> Google API (Target Name).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just have to create Android Project -> Google API (Target Name).

Here's how to set the build target, if you are developing on Eclipse with ADT:

If you want to **add Maps to an existing application**, **right-click the project** in Package Explorer, choose **Properties > Android** and then select a build target from the list displayed. You must choose the "Google APIs" build target.

If you are creating a **new Android project** in Eclipse, the New Project Wizard will ask you to specify the build target for the application. You must choose the **"Google APIs"** build target.

Full Reference Here : http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

All Android phones have the Google Map library available. These are not strictly part of the Android core operating system but instead are offered as extensions. I don't know of any vendors who do not implement these extensions though it is possible. Unless you are developing for some obscure Android phone/tablet/device you can be sure that the Maps library will be available.